# restlet integration with SOAP

Tags: soap, restlet

I am exploring Restlet for my next project. One of the requirements is to communicate with a legacy SOAP-based service. What is the best practice to provide RESTful style to clients, but communicate via SOAP to this back-end server?

Answer (score 0):

Restlet is offering a complete HTTP client API, so even if your backend is a SOAP server, you can still communicate with it.

Although Restlet doesn't include a usual SOAP stack, you can easily use FreeMarker/Velocity templates to send SOAP messages and XPath processing to extract valuable content from answers.